# C++ template specialization with templated parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I try to write a templated class called Null as below;

```
template <class Type>
class Null;

template <>
class Null<std::string> {
  public:
    Null() {}
    operator std::string() const {
        return std::string();
    }
};
```

so far works good for string

but I want to write something like

```
template<> class Null<boost::shared_ptr<T>>
{
public:
    NUll(){}
    operator boost::shared_ptr<T>() const
    {
        return boost::shared_ptr<T>();
    }
};
```

But it won't compile, I tested other ways and couldn't work it out. How can I do this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your specialization needs a template parameter (or parameters) you better mention them:

```
template <typename T>
class Null<boost::shared_ptr<T>>
{
    // ...
};
```

Note that the list of template parameters in the primary type and in the specialization don't have any relationship! In particular, you can have many template arguments for a specialization. The canonical example is `std::function<...>`:

```
template <typename> class function; // primary template
template <typename RC, typename... Args>
class function<RC(Args...)> {
    // definition
};
```

In the case of `std::function<...>` the primary is even never defined!